# validar que un campo de texto solo admita enteros y no esté vacío en vue.js

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabajando con `vue.js` y necesito que en un campo de texto solo pueda ingresar valores enteros, además de no permitir que el valor de la cantidad sea 0, y si el campo está vacío, asignarle el valor 1. Hasta el momento intenté esto para no permitir decimales:

```
<input type="number" min="1" @keydown="filterKey"></input>

filterKey(e){
  const key = e.key;
  if (key === '.')
  return e.preventDefault();
}
```

pero no sé cómo controlar los otros requerimientos, ¿alguna idea de cómo puedo hacer esto?

Answer (score 0):

Evita que se ingresen caracteres diferentes de 0-9 cuando se presiona la tecla y se analiza keyCode para facilitar la comparación. Cuando el campo pierde el foco (onblur) revisar el valor para saber si se asigna 1:

```js
function filterKey(e) {
    // Si el código es menor que 48 (0) o mayor que 57 (9)
    if(e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57) {
        // No se agrega
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}

function checaValor(item) {
    // Obtener valor actual
    let valor = parseInt(item.value);
    // Si no es número o es menor de 1
    if(isNaN(valor) || valor < 1) {
        // Asignar 1
        item.value = 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="" min="1" onkeydown="filterKey(event);" required onblur="checaValor(this);">
```

Desconozco `vue.js` y no pude hacerlo funcionar aquí, pero creo que el input quedaría más o menos así:

```
<input type="number" value="" min="1" @keydown="filterKey(event);" required @blur="checaValor(this);">
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer que la entrada del usuario se introduje en como un numero usando `v.model.number="numberValue"`, para detectar las condiciones (numero entero mayor a 0) he usado eventos emitidos el cual detecta los eventos y los cambios de los valores, este para cumplir con las condiciones proporcionadas en el método `emitValue`, las cuales son reemplazar el numero menor o igual a 0 y redondear el valor (sin detectar decimales lo cual causaría una computación extra en números enteros).

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
      numberValue: 1
  },
  props: {
    modelValue: Number,
    modelModifiers: {
      default: () => ({})
    }
  },
  emits: ['update:emitUpdate'],
  methods: {
    emitValue(e) {
      this.numberValue = e.target.value
      if (this.numberValue <= 0) {
        this.numberValue = 1
      }
      this.$emit('update:emitValue', Math.round(this.numberValue));
      this.numberValue = Math.round(this.numberValue);
    }
  },
  computed: {
      value: {
        get() {
            return this.value
        },
        set(val) {
            this.$emit('update:emitValue', val)
        }
    }
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<input id="example" v-model.number="numberValue" @input="emitValue" min=1 />
```